# Pillow ImageDraw how to limit the size of the image based on text to be written in the image itself

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create a single image that has a bit of padding above and below the text but no padding whatsoever (unless the user adds a blank space in the string). To my understanding I'd need to generate some sort of size combining the defined `font size` and the string itself but I don't know how to get this information to add to `Image.new()` method. I have tried to look for a get size from the `draw.text()` and then update the `Image.new()` but I don't seem to be able to get a sizing at all.

The sample code I've been running (though it require your own `arial.ttf` file as that's how I understood you need to load it up):

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def generate_image():
    myString= 'Joe Doe'
    font_size = int(font_size_entry.get())
    background_color = background_color_entry.get()
    
    # Create an Image object with PIL
    image = Image.new("RGB", (len(myString)*font_size, font_size), background_color)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    
    # Load a font (you may need to specify the font file path)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", font_size)
    
    # Calculate text size and position
    
    # Draw the text on the image
    draw.text((0, 0), myString, fill="white", font=font)
    # Save the image as PNG
    image.save("generated_image.png")

# Create the main tkinter window
main_window = tk.Tk()
main_window.title("Image Generator")

# Create and pack input fields
ttk.Label(main_window, text="Font Size:").pack()
font_size_entry = ttk.Entry(main_window)
font_size_entry.pack()

ttk.Label(main_window, text="Background Color:").pack()
background_color_entry = ttk.Entry(main_window)
background_color_entry.pack()

# Create and pack the generate button
generate_button = ttk.Button(main_window, text="Generate Image", command=generate_image)
generate_button.pack()

# Start the tkinter main loop
main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: If it helped, please consider accepting my answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the documentation of PIL or more specific into the [documentation of the ImageFont class](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#) you will find the `getlength(text, *args, **kwargs)` method of said class wich returns the width of the text.

I also took the liberty of rewriting your code in an object-oriented way (which I consider more concise when working with tkinter):

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Label, Entry, Button


class ImgGenerator(Tk):
    # set fixed parameters as class variables
    myString = 'Joe Doe'

    # use the init method to instantiate all elements of your gui
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # set Window title
        self.title("Image Generator")
        # Create and pack input fields
        Label(self, text="Font Size:").pack()
        self.font_size_entry = Entry(self)
        self.font_size_entry.pack()
        Label(self, text="Background Color:").pack()
        self.background_color_entry = Entry(self)
        self.background_color_entry.pack()
        # Create and pack the generate button
        self.generate_button = Button(self, text="Generate Image", command=self.generate)
        self.generate_button.pack()

    def generate(self):
        # get input values
        font_size = int(self.font_size_entry.get())
        background_color = self.background_color_entry.get()
        # get font
        font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", font_size)
        # Calculate text width
        width = int(font.getlength(ImgGenerator.myString))
        # Create an Image object with PIL
        image = Image.new("RGB", (width, font_size), background_color)
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
        # Draw the text on the image
        draw.text((0, 0), ImgGenerator.myString, fill="white", font=font)
        # Save the image as PNG
        image.save("generated_image.png")


img_gen = ImgGenerator()  # instantiate your gui


if __name__ == '__main__':
    img_gen.mainloop()
```